# Replacing all values in a dataframe above 100 to value relative to 100. i.e. 120 to 80

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to produce a dataframe containing values relative to values in one column for comparison.

Minimal example:

```r
library(tidyverse) # for pipes and mutates etc.

road_id <- c("road_1", "road_2")
roadFunction <- c("B", "B")
lm1_mean <- c(2,3,4,7)
lm2_mean <- c(5,9,3,2)
lm_estimate <- c(5,5,5,5)

widths <- data.frame(road_id, roadFunction, lm1_mean, lm2_mean, lm_estimate)

normalise_widths <- function(x) {
  x <- x / widths$lm_estimate * 100
  x <- replace(x, x > 100, (100 - (x - 100)))
}


# normalised comparison relative to known
norm_widths <- widths %>%
  mutate_at(vars(3:length(widths)), normalise_widths)
```

I expect values above 100 to be changed to values relative to 100. So for example the value of 7 in lm1_mean is assigned 160. Due to being 160% relative to 5. This works, but I want to change this value to 100 - 60 so 40, indicating the level of inaccuracy relative to 100. I think I'm misunderstanding how mutate_at should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `ifelse` here instead of `replace`. Also don't reference `widths$lm_estimate` directly into the function instead pass it as an argument.

```
normalise_widths <- function(x, y) {
    ifelse(x > y, 100 - ((x/y) * 100 - 100), x/y * 100) 
}

library(dplyr)
widths %>% mutate_at(3:ncol(widths), ~normalise_widths(., lm_estimate))

#Can also pass use `starts_with`
#widths %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("lm")), ~normalise_widths(., lm_estimate))

#  road_id roadFunction lm1_mean lm2_mean lm_estimate
#1  road_1            B       40      100         100
#2  road_2            B       60       20         100
#3  road_1            B       80       60         100
#4  road_2            B       60       40         100
```

---

This can also be applied using base R with `lapply`

```
widths[3:ncol(widths)] <- lapply(widths[3:ncol(widths)], 
                                normalise_widths, widths$lm_estimate)
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I had to alter the ifelse slightly to get the result I wanted: `normalise_widths <- function(x, y) {
    ifelse(x > y, 100 - ((x/y) * 100 - 100), x/y * 100) 
}
`

Comment: @CillianBerragan I see. I have corrected the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
widths %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("lm")),  ~ 
       case_when(. > lm_estimate ~ ((./lm_estimate) * 100 - 100),
                   TRUE ~ ./lm_estimate * 100))
#   road_id roadFunction lm1_mean lm2_mean lm_estimate
#1  road_1            B       40      100         100
#2  road_2            B       60       80         100
#3  road_1            B       80       60         100
#4  road_2            B       40       40         100
```